# Find first character of string, then compare it with a symbol c++

Tags: c++

Attempting to check the first character of a string to see if it contains a "/".

```
string pathname = "/test";
if(pathname.at(0) == "/")
{
    // if first character is a slash then delete the slash
    // but only delete the slash if it's the first character
    pathname.erase(pathname.begin()+0);
}
```

I understand that the above code will not work because pathname.at(0) is considered an int.

I'm sure this has been asked before. But I have looked around a lot. I've seen the substr method the find method and many others. I can't seem to get them working right though.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::string::at()` returns a (reference to a) `char`, not an `int`.  `"/"` is a null-terminated string, not a `char`.  Change `"/"` to `'/'`, then the code will work.  Also, `std::string::erase()` is overloaded to take either an index or an iterator, so you could optionally change `pathname.erase(pathname.begin()+0)` to just `pathname.erase(0)`.

Comment: You're right. That would be more efficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use **single quote** for character constant.

```
if(pathname.at(0) == '/')
                     ^ ^
```

Double quotes, no matter how many characters are inside, represents a **C-style string**. You can't compare a character to a C-string.

Answer (score 0):

You compare the first symbol code with a pointer to string. Try to compare the first symbol with the char.

```
if(pathname.at(0) == '/')
```